# Sending SMS texts in Python without the need for a 3rd party API?

Tags: python, sms

Does anyone know what would go into sending text messages with Python WITHOUT the need for a 3rd party API? What knowledge do I need to have to achieve such a thing? I've only been coding for a few months, so I still consider myself fairly new and there's a lot I don't know about networking. I know there are services like Twilio that offer a python library for sending text messages, but if I wanted to type out my own script, from scratch, what would need to go into it. I'm willing to read some documentation if that's necessary as long as it's not hundreds of pages long. Being as detailed as possible in your response is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

This can be done by sending an email via SMTP to the SMS gateway of the carrier of the recipient phone number. Each carrier [has a unique email address](https://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/17056/%7E/list-of-mobile-carrier-gateway-addresses) usually in the form of `{number}@{host}`. Within Python, you can use the builtin [smptlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html) (or [aiosmtplib](https://github.com/cole/aiosmtplib)) library to send the email. I wrote an example script [here](https://github.com/acamso/demos/blob/master/_email/send_txt_msg.py) to send using GMail.

Comment: Hi Acamso, how do we get the username and password of the carrier gateway that we are trying to use?

Comment: @PrateekGoyal The carrier gateway is the recipient email (no password required). The password is for the sender email (your email) for sending the SMS via SMTP.

Answer (score 4):

Please tell me if I did not understand your question correctly, then I will try to improve it or I'll delete it.

Sending an SMS requires something, that can send an SMS. Which is normally not your laptop / PC, except it has a SIM card and a mobile phone modem. So you need a mobile phone or a service, that offers sending SMS if you subscribe / pay.

Most professional available services allow to send an SMS with simple HTTP GET or POST requests, so you don't need a third party python module, but you must connect to a third party web API in most cases the python code is really simple, but first you need an SMS service provider

Some services also allow sending SMS via SMTP (sending emails) which
@acamso adresses in [his response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66958722/858675)

If you have an Android device you could install `shellms` on it ( https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.android.shellms/ ) connect it via USB to your PC and use `adb` to send SMS, which will be billed on your phone's bill / contract.

I am not aware of any SMS service, that is for free, so if you subscribe to an SMS provider it will provide you with an API, that can normally very easily be handled from python.